# Swift + Objective C - Extra Argument 'withCompletionBlock' in call

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm a little new to Swift and Objective-C (and by that I mean I started last week) so if this is a duplicate question I'm sorry in advance.

In short I seem to be having trouble with calling a method. One part of the code is in Objective-C and the other part is in Swift. I imported the Objective-C file in to the Swift file through a bridging header file if that helps.

Declaration of method (in Objective-C):

```
- (NSUInteger)fetchTeamsForEventKey:(NSString *)eventKey withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *teams, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error))completionBlock {
    NSString *apiMethod = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"event/%@/teams", eventKey];

    NSUInteger taskId = [[TBAKit sharedKit] callArrayMethod:apiMethod modelClass:[TBATeam class] andCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *modelObjects, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(modelObjects, totalCount, error);
    }];
    return taskId;
}
```

Implementation of method (Swift):

```
TBAKit.fetchTeamsForEventKey("2015cacg", withCompletionBlock: {(teams:NSArray, totalCount:NSInteger, error:NSError) in //The error appears in this line.
    if error {
    NSLog("Unable to fetch event - %@", error.localizedDescription)
    return
    }

    teamList = teams
})
```

The source code for the declaration method is in this GitHub Repo: https://github.com/ZachOrr/TBAKit. It's in the file TBAKit/TBAKit+EventMethods.m

**Edit:** I also tried the code with each of the following:

```
-> UInt
```

and

```
-> Int
```

**Edit 2:** So the solution mentioned by t4nhpt did work as it was intended to, but in turn another problem presented itself. I had to replace

```
teamList = teams
```

with

```
self.teamList = teams
```

Now I'm getting the error: "cannot assign a value of type 'anyobject' to a value of type '[TBATeam]'" on the line

```
self.teamList = teams
```

My declaration of the variable is

```
var teamList = [TBATeam]()
```

**Edit 3:** I solved the problem specified in EDIT 2 by converting each object inside teams to TBATeam. Sorry for the stupid mistake.

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me a different error:

Cannot invoke 'fetchTeamsForEventKey' with an argument list of type (String, withCompletionBlock: (NSArray, NSInteger, NSError) -> _)

Comment: Provide the full exact error message i the question.

Comment: When Xcode hint method, at the `withCompletionBlock` parameter, you should press `Enter` key, and it will generate code for you. This is more exact than you type.

Comment: zaph: I did provide the full exact error message in the question.

Comment: t4nhpt: I tried that but it doesn't give me an auto complete option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
TBAKit.sharedKit().fetchTeamsForEventKey("2015cacg") { (teams, totalCount, error) -> Void in
            // your code
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That did help solve the extra argument problem, but now it's created an error on the line 'teamList = teams' saying "Implicit use of self in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit." And with me being new at this, I don't really know what that means.

Comment: I realized the error that I was making. Now I have a new error. I explained it in **Edit 2:** above